# Inserting an Extra Slash for Directories in Python

Tags: python, directory, string-formatting

I'm using EasyGui to return a specified folder path, but the problem is that the path is something like the following:

'C:\folder\sub_folder'

How do I add an extra slash to each one so I can use the path later in my code?

```
from easygui import *

def main():
    print chooseActiveView()

def chooseActiveView():
    folder = diropenbox()
    return folder

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you don't need to.

```
>>> 'C:\\folder\\sub_folder'
'C:\\folder\\sub_folder'
>>> print 'C:\\folder\\sub_folder'
C:\folder\sub_folder
```

Using `\\` is a common practice to include backslashes in strings **specified in source code** (or the interpreter). This is because the backslash character in source code is typically used as a escape character to introduce non-printable characters into a string.

On most UI frameworks, however, this doesn't happen if you ask for input to a user. A backslash inside a string provided from user input in a typical UI framework is the actual backslash character,  which is what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. I was trying it in the interpreter, and I was getting some errors. It works fine when I run the program though.